# Does a priority concepts exists on voters?

Tags: symfony, silex

I need to develop on a web portal a voter System with Silex framework (based on Symfony components).

These various voters will check if the current user is in the good country, if he subscibes to which program, if he activate the advertising on the site, ... I use them with the Unanime rule.

But I also would like to use the role system, and I need that this role voter has hight priority over the rest.

That is to say if the role voter abstain, then others voters can decide with a consensus decision, in any other case it's the role consensus I want to get.

Does Symfony provides tool to do it? I already simulate with matrix these case with Affirmative and Unanime decision managment, but I didn't found how to make the Role Voter more important than other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have to write your own `AccessDecisionManager` to perform it:

In my case I need that the `RoleHierarchyVoter` overwrite other votes, excepts if it abstains. If it abstains I use an unanimous strategy:

```
class AccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManagerInterface {

    private $voters;

    public function __construct(array $voters) {
        $this->voters = $voters;
    }

    public function decide(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null) {
        $deny = 0;

        foreach ($this->voters as $voter) {
            $result = $voter->vote($token, $object, $attributes);
            if ($voter instanceof RoleHierarchyVoter) {
                if ($result === VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED)
                    return true;
                elseif ($result === VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED)
                    return false;
                else
                    continue;
            }else {
                if ($result === VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED)
                    $deny++;
            }
        }

        if ($deny > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

To register my custom AccessDecisionManager:

```
$app['security.access_manager'] = $app->share(function (Application $app) {
    return new AccessDecisionManager($app['security.voters']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set priority for your voter:

```
your_voter:
    class: # ...
    public: false
    arguments: 
      # ...   
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter , priority: 255 }
```

Comment: do you have any links to this functionality into the documentation ?

Comment: @Fractaliste https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml#L110